# xgettext: No such file or directory

Tags: gettext

I'm using this command line:

```
xgettext -kT._ -kT._n:1,2 -kT._p:1c,2 -kT._pn:1c,2,3 
   -LC# --omit-header --from-code=UTF-8 -o messages.pot
   -c -n -p PO ./TransClassOne.cs
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting this message from xgettext:

```
xgettext.exe: error while opening "._" for reading: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Using MacOS:

1. [Install gettext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8403988/1573036) tool
2. If already installed, you might want to reinstall - `brew reinstall gettext`
3. If using some bash profile ([oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) e.g.), export `gettext` and update it:

   - `nano ~/.zshrc`
   - at the end of file add `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"` and save it
   - update profile with `. ~/.zshrc` ; pay attention to not forget the dot before `zshrc`
   - restart your terminal (optional)
4. Run your command again.