# django i18n: Make sure you have GNU gettext tools

Tags: python, django

I try `django-admin.py makemessages -l zh_CN` but has error :

```
CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.
```

after I use brew install gettext,it still get wrong.
Do I need to do something? here is my terminal screenshot
Please guide me thank you.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internationalisation Django (on OSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860188/internationalisation-django-on-osx)

Comment: This helped me a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55010488/7091922

Answer (score 45):

In Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gettext
```

Answer (score 42):

For Mac users, after installing Homebrew and gettext as @Louis Barranqueiro says (steps 1 and 2):

1. Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) : `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. Install GNU gettext : `brew install gettext`

You shouldn't use `brew link gettext --force` in step 3, because it is risky (as Brew advises if you try). A better workaround is to set a new `PATH variable` for your virtual environment. So, in the `postactivate` file, which is located in the bin folder of your virtual environment folder, type:

```
export TEMP_PATH=$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.7/bin
```

Note that you have to replace `0.19.7` by the version that is installed in your machine.

And in your `predeactivate` file, which is located in the same folder of `postactivate` file, type:

```
export PATH=$TEMP_PATH
unset TEMP_PATH
```

Now you can use the `python manage.py makemessages -l <desired_language>` without worries. :)

Cheers.

Comment: This is the best answer by far

Comment: Thanks! Keeping the `TEMP_PATH` and restoring it in the predeactivate file was not necessary for me. It looks like virtualenv takes care of that already. Tested with virtualenv 15.0.1.

Comment: I did not find any `postactivate` file in the bin folder of my virtual environment folder...

Comment: Did not work for me on `High Sierra`. `/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin/` this path worked for me.

Comment: For people who are using `venv`, just add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/YOUR_VERSION/bin` to the bottom of the `activate` file.

Answer (score 13):

This procedure worked for me **(OSX 10.11.2 - python v3.5 and Django 1.8)**
It should work with your configuration.

Install gettext GNU tools with Homebrew using Terminal

1. Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)  : `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. Install GNU gettext : `brew install gettext`
3. Create symlink : `brew link gettext --force`

Answer (score 10):

This solution worked for me ( win. 7, 8 and 10 )

You need to download two folders:

- gettext-runtime_0.18.1.1-2_win32
- gettext-tools-dev_0.18.1.1-2_win32

You can find them [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/).

- After you download them, unzip them and add the directory of the bin file of the both folders to the system variables `PATH` of your pc.
- You will also need a file named **libstdc++-6.dll** download it from [here](https://www.dll-files.com/libstdc++-6.dll.html) and place it in your system directory. You will find adequate details on system directory [here](https://www.dll-files.com/support/#208335895).

And that’s it. Hope it is useful for you.

Comment: How can I get 64 bit files?

Answer (score 4):

Just below solution solved my problem. I am using Windows 10 64bit

1- Go to this link : 
https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html

2- Download 32 or 64 bit **shared** and **static** windows installation files

3-Install both of files
4-Restart your computer

Answer (score 3):

Hi first of all make sure that your virtual environment is not in your root folder. I think it's better practice to keep your virtual environment outside of the root folder. Obviously make sure your environment is activated. Of course make sure you have gettext installed as well.

**If your env folder is in your root folder**

To test this just make sure you add {% load i18n %} in all your templates, choose a template and do something like this:

```
<h1>{% trans 'My Test to be translated' %}</h1>
```

Now run this command

```
django-admin makemessages -l 'zh_CN' -i your_venv
```

(Make sure you replace `your_venv` to the name of your virtual environment.

After you run the above command, you should get this in your terminal.

> processing locale zh_CN

Now you should have a locale folder like this: `locale/cn/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`

Now you will need to compile the messages. Run this command

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

In your locale folder, now you should get you should see django.mo file as well, but you will notice the difference in django.po file. Just add your translation there, and you can test again by setting your en language to LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh_CN' then just refresh and test the h1 string will be translated to Chinese.

In order for the above to work in your settings.py ensure you have this here, for now most important is the LOCALE_PATHS, but please check if this **('zh_CN', _('Chinese')),** is correct

```
LANGUAGES = [
   ('zh_CN', _('Chinese')),
   ('en', _('English')),
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'


TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]
```

In this reply, the most important part is to realize where your virtual environment is located. Reason why you get all these errors.

Please make sure you refer to this video here, it's a great tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xI97sLMd1rM

Answer (score 2):

[@max-malysh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1977620/max-malysh)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860188/internationalisation-django-on-osx/9787791#40387707) solved it for me —without touching system files.

Copy and run each of the following:

```
brew install gettext
GETTEXT_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.8.1/bin"
FILE="venv/bin/activate"
echo "" >> $FILE
echo "export PATH=\$PATH:$GETTEXT_PATH" >> $FILE
source venv/bin/activate
```

1. `GETTEXT_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.8.1/bin"` stores gettext_path in a shell variable —adapt the version number according to what `brew install gettext`
2. `FILE="venv/bin/activate"` stores the path to the venv shell script
3. `echo "" >> $FILE` adds an empty line at the end of the to make sure the next command is on its own line
4. `echo "export PATH=\$PATH:$GETTEXT_PATH" >> $FILE` adds a command to the venv shell script; this command adds the path to gettext binaries to the global `$PATH` variable, so that they are used before OS binaries.
5. `source venv/bin/activate` runs the venv shell script so that variables are properly set. You can run this command more than once.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Docker just simply run below command:

```
apt-get update
```

Then:

```
apt-get install gettext
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use fish shell, another way around is to add this path to `$fish_user_paths`.This variable is prepended to `$PATH`, so you don't have to set it in all your projects.

You can do it with the following command line :

```
set -U fish_user_paths /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.8.1/bin $fish_user_paths
```

Remember to replace `0.19.8.1` with your `gettext` version.

This sets `$fish_user_paths` as a Universal Variable. Here's what `help` says about Universal Variables :

> A universal variable is a variable whose value is shared across all
>   instances of fish, now and in the future – even after a reboot. You
>   can make a variable universal with `set -U`

So setting this variable in your shell once (no need to do it in a config file) will save it even after logging out or rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

that works for windows users.
i am using django 2

1. access this https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html

2 download the static version for your system

3. after downloaded execute the setup.
4. restart your pc and it will work.

That is all. THANKS.!!!!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is hinted in the output from `brew`...

it has installed the GNU gettext but hasn't linked it into your bin directory because OSX already provides a different version of gettext...

so Django doesn't know to run the version you installed from brew.

apparently brew is too cautious here though and you should just link it https://stackoverflow.com/a/9787791/202168

Comment: Don't just link it; let OSX have it's own gettext and let Django use homebrew's variant by overriding the PATH