# Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed. (Django 1.8 and OSX ElCapitan)

Tags: python, django, macos, gettext, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to internationalize a Django app by following the wonderful Django documentation. The problem is when I try to run command to create language files:

```
python manage.py makemessages -l fr
```

It outputs an error :

```
CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.
```

My configuration :

- OS : **OSX El Capitan v10.11.3**
- Python : **v3.5**
- Django : **v1.8**

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Install gettext GNU tools with Homebrew using Terminal

1. Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)  : `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. Install GNU gettext : `brew install gettext`
3. Create symlink : `brew link gettext --force`

Comment: I get the error:
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.7... 
Error: Could not symlink share/info/autosprintf.info
/usr/local/share/info is not writable.

Comment: Did you try with sudo?

Comment: With sudo I get the following:
Error: Cowardly refusing to 'sudo brew link'
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at your own risk

Comment: Should I uninstall gettext and reinstall with sudo?

Comment: Do you have the same configuration ?

Comment: My configuration:
OS : OSX El Capitan 10.11.4
Python: 2.7.10
Django: 1.9.5

Comment: Thanks for your response. Setting path worked for me as suggested in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35579852/38856

Comment: good news :) Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647412/homebrew-could-not-symlink-usr-local-bin-is-not-writable and try `brew doctor` to check if everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `brew doctor` gave me a hint to do chown on some directory, after doing it `brew link gettext --force --overwrite` worked!

Answer (score 24):

**For Windows**:

1. Download [gettext](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html) and install
2. Add in system var PATH: `C:\Program Files\gettext-iconv\bin` (if you didn't it during installation)
3. Check or create in your project directory `locale/`
4. Check or add in *settings.py*: `LOCALE_PATHS = (BASE_DIR + 'locale/', )`

Enjoy by `django-admin makemessages -l fr`. If still repeating don't forget to restart your shell to update env vars

Comment: Please run the command in winodws CMD (press windows+r and then type "cmd") . In vs code terminal is not working.

Comment: Download gettext and `install`. How to install it? There is no install file for windows in it

Comment: Here is the installation file: https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html

Answer (score 19):

First make dir in root project folder with name **`locale`** then run

```bash
    sudo apt install gettext
```

Comment: Made it for me on Ubuntu 20, thx mate ;)

Answer (score 7):

If you try running `link gettext --force` it warns you:

> Note that doing so can interfere with building software.

The safest way to use it is to add gettext binary to your path:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: I have it in .bashrc but .bash_profile also will work, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51038/83258