# Django - Cannot compilemessages in Alpine?

Tags: django, docker, translation, alpine-linux

I'm trying to migrating our docker image to alpine based, but I got a problem that I cannot compile messages during image building.

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Creating working directory
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

# Copying requirements
COPY ./myproject/ .

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
ca-certificates gcc postgresql-dev linux-headers musl-dev \
libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev \
&& pip install -r requirements.txt \
&& find /usr/local \
    \( -type d -a -name test -o -name tests \) \
    -o \( -type f -a -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.pyo' \) \
    -exec rm -rf '{}' + \
&& runDeps="$( \
    scanelf --needed --nobanner --recursive /usr/local \
            | awk '{ gsub(/,/, "\nso:", $2); print "so:" $2 }' \
            | sort -u \
            | xargs -r apk info --installed \
            | sort -u \
)" \
&& apk add --virtual .rundeps $runDeps \
&& apk del .build-deps

RUN python manage.py compilemessages
```

The only problem I have is in the step compiling messages. Here the error

```
CommandError: Can't find msgfmt. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this answer is old, but hope that my answer will help.

You create --virtual packages at the beginning and install them. It's great for your container, because it stays small and clean, but
problem is here

```
&& apk del .build-deps
```

With this command you delete all virtual packages. If `gettext-dev` was here

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
ca-certificates gcc postgresql-dev linux-headers musl-dev \
libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev gettext-dev\
```

It also be deleted.
So if you want that your package stayed inside container you need to add it after main packages install.

For example

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Creating working directory
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

# Copying requirements
COPY ./myproject/ .

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
ca-certificates gcc postgresql-dev linux-headers musl-dev \
libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev \
&& pip install -r requirements.txt \
&& find /usr/local \
    \( -type d -a -name test -o -name tests \) \
    -o \( -type f -a -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.pyo' \) \
    -exec rm -rf '{}' + \
&& runDeps="$( \
    scanelf --needed --nobanner --recursive /usr/local \
            | awk '{ gsub(/,/, "\nso:", $2); print "so:" $2 }' \
            | sort -u \
            | xargs -r apk info --installed \
            | sort -u \
)" \
&& apk add --virtual .rundeps $runDeps \
&& apk del .build-deps

RUN apk add gettext-dev

RUN python manage.py compilemessages
```

Or you could remove this row

```
&& apk del .build-deps
```

but this means that your container will be much bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `gettext` to the dockerfile. You can use: `RUN apk add gettext` for adding that. And the Alpine package link: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/gettext

Comment: Hey Thank you for answering, I tried that but the error still exists.

Comment: Hi, have installed gcc, python dev etc?

Comment: Yes I already added it, you can see in my example dockerfile.

Comment: In that case, I am really out of clue. Sorry

Comment: One last thing, try adding "gettext-dev" as well

Comment: Maybe a better solution is to compilemessage beforehand and commit with git. Because gettext/gettext-dev will bloat the dockerfile because they are being used only once for compiling message

Answer (score 1):

Here is Dockerfile for apline3.8 which I use in my project, it works for `makemessages` and `compilemessages`.

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.8

# postgresql-client is required by psql
# postgresql-dev musl-dev gcc are required by psycopg
# NOTE: there is py3-psycopg2
# linux-headers is required by uwsgi
# gettext-dev is required by ./manage.py makemessages

# TODO: optimize installation by using --virtual
RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
    && apk add postgresql-client \
        postgresql-dev \
        musl-dev \
        gcc \
        linux-headers \
        gettext-dev \
    && pip install pipenv

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8

COPY docker/backend/docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

WORKDIR /project/backend

COPY backend/Pipfile backend/Pipfile.lock /project/backend/

# TODO: use virtualenv?
RUN pipenv install --system --ignore-pipfile --dev
```