# Trying to execute django-admin makemessages in windows 10

Tags: python, django

I´m trying to generate translation file using command **django-admin makemessages -l pt-br** in Windows 10 but unfortunately the files aren´t generated. Here the steps that I followed:

1. Installed gettext library from [mlocati](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html).
2. I also tried several options from [django i18n: Make sure you have GNU gettext tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220052/django-i18n-make-sure-you-have-gnu-gettext-tools/39406251) , this process is more manual.

As the result when i run **django-admin makemessages -l pt-br** looks like that Django is executing something but the directory is not generated in the end.

Here are some peace of code that I have

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

def index(request):
    context = {
        'hello': _('Hello!')
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for translation_example project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '3^*d$5b7$r2$t-0cxmef22l5_)t^cn9i-xkq48zen$u*67)tvm'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'example',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'translation_example.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'translation_example.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And as my template **index.html**

```
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ hello }}</h1>
    <h2>{% trans "My name is SpeedJr" %}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run **django-admin makemessages -l pt-br** shows message `processing locale pt-br`, but at end the directory is not generate with files.

For this example I following this tutorial [A Quick Intro to Translation in Django (Internationalization)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlJ8cGbk8ps)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several tryings and options. I found the error in my case.

If you install any gettext wizard installation some dependences library could not be instaled. (It was my case). According with the post [django i18n: Make sure you have GNU gettext tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220052/django-i18n-make-sure-you-have-gnu-gettext-tools/39406251) in the contribution of [Far](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5387941/far) the problem it was fixed.

According with django documentation, the command "**xgettext --version**" must be run to enable internationalization command. In my case **w64gcc_s_sjlj-1.dll** it was out.